# Make bash script run on both Linux and Solaris

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, opensuse

I am writing a script and my script is required to work both on solaris AND Linux (OpenSuse)

The script simply goes in different directories and compares some files and outputs the difference between the files in a specific manner.

Right now, I am developing it on OpenSuse(linux). Are there some good tips on how I can write/edit the script so it works on both OS?

Thank you in advance

Comment: ... and where is the script?

Comment: Paste the script here, or possible better on unix.stackexchange.com and somebody can probably tell you what won't work. There are quite a few differences in `grep`, `find`, `date`, for example, but often you can work around them, or install the GNU version (there's a package for that in Solaris), so you can use them the same way.

Comment: @janos Is it possible that a script works on both platform? (it's a tool that is required to work on both)

Comment: @Matin probably, but it really depends on the details of what you need to do.

Comment: This question is more about underlying tools like grep and find

Comment: Are you going to be using `bash` on both Solaris and Linux, or are you going to be using `/bin/sh` on both (being wholly different shells)?  If you have `bash` on both, then anything that works on the older shell version (likely the Solaris version) will work on the other.  If you have to use `/bin/sh` or something else, then you have to notch it back and avoid all the `bash` extensions over the POSIX shell.  And make sure you avoid the GNU extensions to the commands you use.

Answer (score 1):

Writing portable script is easy or at least should it be, just use commands specified by the POSIX standard and stick to their documented options and behavior.